# Is safari box model different from other browsers and if so, how to resolve it?

Tags: safari, css

I'm having a problem with layout in Safari that works fine in Chrome and FF. It seems that Safari includes the padding within the width while Chrome and FF don't. So what's 630px in FF 
due to width + padding is only 600px in Safari. This: [Padding in mozilla firefox and in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367416/padding-in-mozilla-firedox-and-in-safari) seems to show that the box model is different in Safari. If so I would expect a standard solution would already have come up but when I google this, it seems that hardly anyone has this problem.

Is the box model in Safari really different and is there a standard solution? Or do I just have to 'debug' my CSS?

EDIT: apparently it's because the div was using display: table. When I changed it to display: block, it worked as expected. It's still strange though because it's working fine in other browsers (display: table).

Answer (score 0):

Which doctype are you using? When I use < !DOCTYPE html > (the HTML5 doctype declaration) Safari and Chrome's padding behaviour is definitely exactly the same, and as the standards dictate.

Comment: I use <!doctype html>. I got the 630px vs 600px values by checking in the element inspector of chrome and safari (ex. div.wrap_to_center 630px x 440px on the highlighted div). This is the way to measure it isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS box-sizing handles the box model. By default it's set to the 'normal' but probably incorrect 'content-box'. Support for box-sizing is reasonable across browsers now so you can probably move to 'border-box' but will need to handle it differently in IE6/7 (if you support them).

AFAIK Safari (webkit) should respect this.

Comment: If you meant that I should try to set the div to box-sizing:content-box, it didn't change anything. And this is supposed to be the default anyway.

Comment: Can you post a link? Which Safari are you looking at it in? Windows/Mac? What version?